# Error al compilar un proyecto en Android Studio

Tags: android, build

Actualice a la versión 3.0 de Android estudio, ahora al momento de cargar mi proyecto me aparece este error:

> files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited

He intentado **sync project with gradle files**. Cerrar y abrir pero por lo que he notado es que no me esta reconociendo los XML, he investigado y revisado las posibles soluciones de otras preguntas a este mismo problema pero no me ha funcionado.

Esta es la imagen del `manifest`, cabe mencionar que al abrir los `xml` de las vistas, no me permite cargar el preview, ni ver el diseño, por eso pienso que no esta cargando correctamente el proyecto, gracias¡¡
[image: Imagen del manifest]

[image: imagen del build.gradle]

[image: en los XML no puedo ver el preview]

Comment: Agrega una captura del archivo gradle.build (app)

Comment: Listo he agregado la captura que me solicitaste, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Logre solucionarlo gracias a la información de este link [About Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html)

especificamente gracias a este parrafo:

Improved incremental resource processing using AAPT2, which is enabled by default. If you are experiencing issues while using AAPT2, you can disable it by setting **android.enableAapt2=false** in your gradle.properties file and restarting the Gradle daemon by running ./gradlew --stop from the command line.

**solamente tuve que pegar esta linea: android.enableAapt2=false en el gradle.Properties**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estas tratando de editar un archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` que se genera al compilar tu proyecto, **los archivos dentro de `/app/build/` no deben editarse**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de hecho es lo que indica este mensaje,

> "Archivos dentro del folder "build" son generados y no deben ser
>   editados"

:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` que debes editar es el que se encuentra dentro de la ruta: `/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`**

---

Si eliges visualizar tu proyecto como "`Android`", aquí se encuentra tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si eliges visualizar tu proyecto como "`Project`", aquí se encuentra tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, es correcto lo que me dices el detalle esta en que yo no intente modificar el manifest de esa ubicacion, bueno al menos no lo hice aproposito, cual sería la solución?

Comment: Hola @GilbertFlores , en realidad estabas editando el archivo dentro de /build, en Android Studio se puede ver la ruta en la parte superior del archivo que estas editando en ese momento. La solución es abrir el correcto AndroidManifest.xml, agregué una actualización para que puedas ubicar correctamente el archivo.